# Find endomorphisms $α$ and $β$ of $V$ satisfying the condition that $αβ$ is not nilpotent but $cα+dβ$ is nilpotent for all $c, d ∈ \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^3$. Find endomorphisms $α$ and $F$ of $V$
satisfying the condition that $αβ$ is not nilpotent but $cα+dβ$ is nilpotent
for all $c, d ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

I tried $(cα+dβ)^2=c^2α^2+cd(αβ+βα)+d^2β^2=0$. But that don't seem to work, and I don't have another idea that guess and try.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but I think that's no true, if we take $\alpha:(x,y,z)\mapsto (0,x,0)$ and $\beta:(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,0,0)$ both are nilpotent but the sum is not.

Comment: You are correct; I was thinking of the case where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will denote by $A$, $B$ the desired endomorphisms. The condition $aA+bB$ nilpotent for all $a,b\in \mathbb R$ implies
$$
0=(aA+bB)^3 = (aA+bB)(aA+bB)(aA+bB) \\= a^3A^3 + a^2b( A^2B + ABA + BA^2) +
ab^2(B^2A+BAB+A^2B) + b^3 B^3,
$$
hence
$$
A^3 =0, \\
A^2B + ABA + BA^2=0, \\
B^2A+BAB+A^2B=0,\\
B^3=0.
$$
The first and the latter condition imply that $A,B$ have to be nilpotent.

Moreover, the condition $AB$ not nilpotent implies $A^2\ne0$ and $B^2\ne0$, otherwise the second or third line would yield $ABAB=0$.

Following Travis hint, you have to choose 
$$
A=\pmatrix{ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 },
$$
and $B$ similar to $A$.

---

After fiddling around with the conditions on $B$ implied by $A^2B + ABA + BA^2=0$, I found one matrix $B$ that apparently does fulfill all the conditions
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\
     1&0&1\\
     0&-1&0\\}.
$$
Still some high-level inside into this problem is highly appreciated :)

Comment: How do you conclude $$
A^3 =0, \\
A^2B + ABA + BA^2=0, \\
B^2A+BAB+A^2B=0,\\
B^3=0.
$$ beside $a(A^2B + ABA + BA^2)+b(B^2A+BAB+A^2B)=0$

Comment: Set $a=0$, $b=1$, then $a=1$, $b=0$. The argument behind is comparison of coefficients in polynomials.

Comment: Indeed these two work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. Since $c \alpha + d \beta$ is nilpotent for all $c, d$, in particular $\alpha, \beta$ are nilpotent.
2. Appealing to the Jordan Canonical Form gives that, up to similarity, there are only two nonzero nilpotent matrices in $M(3, \Bbb R)$, namely
   $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: products of these two matrices are again nilpotent...

Comment: @daw The two matrices in (2) are not candidates for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The hints together tell us, however, that for any solution, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must both have one form or the other. In fact, since the properties in the question are invariant under similarity, we may take $\alpha$ to be one of the matrices or the other.